# SQL para carregar apenas parte de uma string

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Tenho a seguinte query abaixo, porém, preciso que na coluna DE traga apenas os textos apos a palavra "Exclusão", e na coluna PARA traga somente o texto a partir da palavra "Inclusão". Porém, hoje, ele está trazendo o texto todo e eu preciso só o que vier "Exclusão: XXXXXXX " e "Inclusão: YYYYY".

Está carregando a linha toda e não está respeitando o limite que foi criado.

Código:

```
SELECT
"DATA",
CONTRATO,
TIPO_CONTRATO,
STATUS_CONTRATO,
MODALIDADE_FATURAMENTO,
PROMOCAO,
SUBSTR(observacao,INI) AS DE,
SUBSTR(observacao2,LM) AS PARA,
LOGIN,
USUARIO,
AREA
FROM 
(SELECT 
BASE.*,
INSTR(observacao2,' Inclusão: ',1) as LM,
INSTR(observacao2, ' Exclusão: ',1) as ini
FROM
(
SELECT 
"ID",
A."DATA",
A.CONTRATO,
NUMERO_CONTRATO,
ACAO,
DESCRICAO_ACAO,
OBSERVACAO,
NUMERO_PROTOCOLO,
LOGIN,
USUARIO,
A.AREA,
B.PROMOCAO,
TIPO_CONTRATO,
STATUS_CONTRATO,
MODALIDADE_FATURAMENTO,
replace (replace(a.OBSERVACAO,'Inclusão:',' Inclusão:'),'Exclusão:','     Exclusão:  ') as observacao2
 from DBMDTH.vm_dth_notas_contrato A, DBMDTH.VM_DTH_USUARIO_APLICA_PROMOCAO B, DBMDTH.VM_DBM_CONTRATO E where A."DATA" BETWEEN  '01/07/18' and '31/07/18'
```

Podem ajudar?

Comment: Acho que faltam alguns parêntesis na sua consulta SQL. Da forma como está construída é bem difícil perceber o que é suposto ela retornar!

Answer (score 2):

O comando SUBSTR precisa de 3 argumentos:

```
SUBSTRING( string, start_position, length )
```

Nesse caso as linhas abaixo podem ser substituídas de:

```
SUBSTR(observacao,INI) AS DE,
SUBSTR(observacao2,LM) AS PARA,
```

Para:

```
SUBSTR(observacao, 10, LEN(observacao) - 10) AS DE,
SUBSTR(observacao2, 10, LEN(observacao2) - 10) AS PARA,
```

Por favor, veja se isso te ajuda.

Comment: Pela descrição do problema, não me ficou claro se as palavras **"inclusão"** e **"exclusão"** estão sempre no começo ou não. Mas de modo geral achei sua resposta certa

Comment: Rodrigo, a palavra inclusão ou exclusão aparece no meio de todo o conteúdo retornado em um campo.
Tentei e aparece o erro:

ORA-00904: "LEN": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 9 Coluna: 25

to rodando no Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

Na pergunta você não especificou em qual banco está rodando, essa query fiz utilizando SQL Server. Mas basicamente faz o substring até o ":"

```
SELECT
    T.Texto
    ,SUBSTRING(T.Texto, 1, CHARINDEX(':', t.Texto))
FROM
(
    SELECT
        'Inclusão: YYYYY' AS Texto
) AS T
```

adaptando para o seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
    SELECT
    "DATA",
    CONTRATO,
    TIPO_CONTRATO,
    STATUS_CONTRATO,
    MODALIDADE_FATURAMENTO,
    PROMOCAO,
    --SUBSTR(observacao,INI) AS DE,
    SUBSTRING(observacao, 1, CHARINDEX(':', observacao)) AS DE,
    --SUBSTR(observacao2,LM) AS PARA,
    SUBSTRING(observacao2, 1, CHARINDEX(':', observacao2)) AS PARA,
    LOGIN,
    USUARIO,
    AREA
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        BASE.*,
        INSTR(observacao2,' Inclusão: ',1) as LM,
        INSTR(observacao2, ' Exclusão: ',1) as ini
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            "ID",
            A."DATA",
            A.CONTRATO,
            NUMERO_CONTRATO,
            ACAO,
            DESCRICAO_ACAO,
            OBSERVACAO,
            NUMERO_PROTOCOLO,
            LOGIN,
            USUARIO,
            A.AREA,
            B.PROMOCAO,
            TIPO_CONTRATO,
            STATUS_CONTRATO,
            MODALIDADE_FATURAMENTO,
            replace (replace(a.OBSERVACAO,'Inclusão:',' Inclusão:'),'Exclusão:','     Exclusão:  ') as observacao2
        from
            DBMDTH.vm_dth_notas_contrato A, 
            DBMDTH.VM_DTH_USUARIO_APLICA_PROMOCAO B, 
            DBMDTH.VM_DBM_CONTRATO E 
        where 
            A."DATA" BETWEEN  '01/07/18' and '31/07/18'
    )
)
```

Comment: Marconcilio, boa tarde. Pode "exemplificar" direto no meu código como seria? Não entendi como replicar sua sugestao. tnks

Comment: Qual banco você está utilizando? É Oracle?

Comment: o que tem eu ? ????